# Is it possible to say "For every time I've known"

Tags: meaning

Hello native or very good speakers!

Can I say
"This has been this way for every time I've known?"
As this is part of a poem, I'd really like to keep "known" at the end as it rhymes with the line before.
It sounds right to me but a friend pointed out that it sounded strange to him. 
I want to express that a certain situation was that way as long as I can remember.
1) Is it correct?
2) If it isn't, will it get the point across?

Thank you in advance!

edit:
The whole verse goes
Lonley, but not alone
for every time I've known

Comment: It's understandable, but "... for ..." expects a duration (e.g. *for 5 min*), which "every time I've known" doesn't deliver. Consider "... for as long as I can remember" instead.

Comment: What about for as long as I've known? As I stated above I really like to keep known there.

Comment: That sounds fine.

Comment: If you want you can post this as an answer and I'll select it :)

Comment: Do you need to use the term "this way". How about *It has been so for as long as I've known*.

Comment: it's all I've ever known

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence conveys the intent that it has been that way each time you've looked, or for as long as you remember, but it isn't idiomatic.

The word *for* in this context should be followed by a duration - e.g. *for five minutes*. However "every time I've known" isn't a duration.

Consider "... for as long as I've known" instead.